# Entity Framework create a foreign key by referencing primary key of the same table

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to use Entity Framework code-first to create a foreign key by referencing primary key of the same table. Please run the SQL to understand the requirement, though let me best put it up.

I have a `User` class/model that has a property `UserId` (primary key), now I want to have two more properties `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` both as foreign key to `UserId` for the same `User` table

**Table structure**

```
UserID(PK,int,not null)
FirstName
LastName
UpdatedBy
CreatedBy(FK,int,not null) -- FK to UserId
UpdatedBy(FK,int, not null)  -- FK to UserId
```

**SQL for reference**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_User_CreatedBy] 
FOREIGN KEY([CreatedBy]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_User_CreatedBy]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_User_UpdatedBy] 
FOREIGN KEY([UpdatedBy]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_User_UpdatedBy]
GO
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: I would make CreatedBy and UpdatedBy nullable, as you might get in troulbe with setting CreatedBy for the first user. UpdatedBy might also be null if there are no updates yet. Can't point to the same user with not nullable constraint.

Comment: Show us your existing code first.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, your problem lies with the non-nullable foreign keys.

You won't be able to add a new user without another user creating it. So how to insert the first user?

Deleting an user seems similarly difficult. The foreign key references would either have to be set to null or cascade delete. Null is not an option, as the reference field is marked as 'not null'. So the delete command would cascade, theoretically removing all entries from the table, eventually. Up until the first user, which can't be deleted as there is no user that created the first user.

No DBMS would/should allow a database design like this.

```
public class User {

    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public Nullable<int> CreatedByRef {get; set;}
    public Nullable<int> UpdatedByRef {get; set;}

    public virtual User CreatedBy {get; set;}
    public virtual User UpdatedBy {get; set;}

}

public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User> {

    public UserMap() {

        ToTable("Users");

        HasKey(t=>t.UserId);

        HasOptional(t=>t.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t=>t.CreatedByRef);
        HasOptional(t=>t.UpdatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t=>t.UpdatedByRef);

    }

}
```